# Error trying to do search for records matching criteria with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am taking a training course, on Udemy, and it had backend code already written, as the course is purely about frontend development. It uses a very simple MongoDB database that I created. I determined that MongoDB version 4.0.10 is installed on my computer, in case that's relevant. When trying to perform a query for matching records, I get the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.
> at MessageStream.messageHandler (I:\DEV\Training\React For the Rest of Us\backend-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:268:20)
> at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at processIncomingData (I:\DEV\Training\React For the Rest of Us\backend-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
> at MessageStream._write (I:\DEV\Training\React For the Rest of Us\backend-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
> at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
> at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
> at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
> (node:51960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To
> terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> After looking into the backend code, I found the following code that is being used to perform the query/search, and I did notice that there are $ symbols in various places.

```
Post.search = function(searchTerm) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof(searchTerm) == "string") {
      let posts = await Post.reusablePostQuery([
        {$match: {$text: {$search: searchTerm}}},
        {$sort: {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}}
      ])
      resolve(posts)
    } else { 
      reject()
    }
  })
}
```

What exactly is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Those `$`s are not the problem. Where do you see the error? The dump should show you the file and line number that throws the error.

Comment: I added rest of error message to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Identical error here. Searching from react using axios in the main app-very simple(supposed to be). It's indicative that in my case when trying to search- "open search mode" from react", mongodb server crashes with mentioned error:
f:\PrgsReact\SimplePost\backend-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:268
callback(new MongoError(document));
MongoError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.
etc..
I'm tried to change npm ver of mongodb and axios inter alia. Thanks.

Comment: When I removed the following line of code, with the comma that preceded it, it worked for me: {$sort: {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}}